# Laravel - 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Tags: php, laravel

This application lets you create a quote of products.  However when they tried to remove an item from the cart they get this error:

> [2015-06-29 20:58:28] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException'
>   with message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in /app/controllers/CustomQuoteController.php:613
>
> #0 /app/controllers/CustomQuoteController.php(613): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...',
>   '/var/www/...', 613, Array)

I removed part of the path name.

Line 613 is the one that reads `if($item_in_cart->name == $custom_quote_item->name)`

```
public function removeFromQuote()
{
    $item_exists = true;

    $custom_quote_item = CustomQuoteItem::find(Input::get('id'));

    $custom_quote_items = Session::get('custom_quote_items');

    if(count($custom_quote_items) > 0 ) 
    {
        foreach($custom_quote_items as $key => $item_in_cart)
        {
            // line 613 below
            if($item_in_cart->name == $custom_quote_item->name)
            {
                unset($custom_quote_items[$key]);

                Session::set('custom_quote_items', $custom_quote_items);

                return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Item has been removed.');
            }
        }
    }

    return Redirect::back()->with('errors', 'Item was not removed.');
}
```

Comment: What type is `$custom_quote_items`? I'm guessing it's a \Illuminate\Support\Collection and not an array, so `if(count($custom_quote_items) > 0 )` won't work, it should be `if( ! $custom_quote_items->isEmpty() )` instead.

Comment: @Quasdunk, That's incorrect. Laravel's collections support array access, and using `count($collection)` works just fine. There's also a `$collection->count()` method available on Collections as well that he could use.

Comment: @SteveBauman Yes, you're right! But I remember running into an issue with this in L4.0 where I spent quite some time finding out that a count on a Collection does not work. But either I don't remember it right or it was fixed in a later version :) Anyway, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: It is an array.  I inherited support on this so learning what they did as well as figuring out the problems.  Would it help to post the whole code in this controller?

Comment: Then either `$item_in_cart` or `$custom_quote_item` is `null`. Could you post the output of `dd($custom_quote_item, $custom_quote_items);`? And make sure `CustomQuoteItem::find(Input::get('id'));` returns something. You might want to do `CustomQuoteItem::findOrFail(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're retrieving properties on both `$item_in_cart` and `$custom_quote_item` on line 613, that's where your problems lie. One of those isn't an object, or do not contain the property `name`, as the exception states.

I'd verify that both variables are objects by using `dd($item_in_cart)`, and update us with the output, my guess is `$item_in_cart` is the issue, since you're retrieving it from the session and looping through it.

Comment: object(CustomQuoteItem)[99]
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'table' => string 'custom_quote_items' (length=18)
  public 'price' => string '$0.60' (length=5)
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string '10255.011010' (length=12)
      'description' => string '10 x 10 x 1' (length=11)
      'quantity' => string '12.000' (length=6)

Comment: I did a    dd ($custom_quote_item);  and it is null.   So now thinking it must be the find part at the top.